# Cannot find input file: makefile.in

Tags: mod-wsgi

I've bin trying to integrate Apache and with Django.

I downloaded the mod_wsgi-3.4 folder from the net and tried running the ./configure command from git bash.

I'm using dev c++ as my c compiler.

I get the following errors:

./configure: line 1877: apxs: command not found ln: creating symbolic link 'Makefile.in' to 'posix-apX.mk.in': No such file directory configure: creating ./config.status config.status:error: cannot find input file: Makefile.in

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Why don't you use the mod_wsgi that comes with your distribution?

Comment: there wasnt anything.

Comment: What distribution are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the location of apxs

```
./configure --with-apxs=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs
```

Comment: can i install the bin folder separately

Comment: You do not have an apache installed?